# The first Stiefel Whitney class v.s. fermion eta invariant v.s. spin structure v.s. $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, characteristic-classes, cobordism

$H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ specifies the 1st cohomology class of manifold $M$ (can be regarded as spacetime) with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficient,

it is often to see that we say the 1st Stiefel Whitney class

> $$w_1 \in H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2), \tag{1}$$

However, it looks to me that when we discuss the spinor bundle (associated to fermion in physics), we also say that the fermion line is related to $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2).$ For example, on the $d$-torus, we need to specify the spin structure on the torus (a spin manifold, with possibly the choice of $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)=H^1(T^d,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\bigoplus_d\mathbb{Z}_2$ along each $S^1$-circle direction.) In other words, we may say that roughly

> $$\text{periodic and anti-periodic boundary condition of fermions} \in H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2),\tag{2}$$

Moreover, one way to understand the fermion moving along a 1-dimensional sub dimensional manifold, may be the spin bordism group generator, say $\eta$, where

> $$\Omega^{1,Spin}(pt)=\mathbb{Z}_2,\tag{3},$$

where $\eta$ on a nontrivial 1-dimensional manifold generates the bordism group.

Moreover, the spin structure seems to imply the trivialization (thus vanishing) of the 2nd Stiefel Whitney class $w_2(M)$. This means that the cohomology class $w_2(M)$ becomes a coboundary in some way thus relates to 1-lower dimensional cochain say $\nu_1$
$$
w_2(M) =\delta \nu_1(M).  \tag{4}
$$
My question is that is the $\nu_1$ related to the $\eta$ or $w_1$ above?

> My question: So how are these eq.(1), (2), (3), (4) are related? Or how are they not related? Can one clarify these with examples?

Comment: A spin structure requires $w_1=0$ (i.e. the manifold is orientable). And what is your co-cycle description of $w_2$ (to specify $\nu_1$)? Anyway, there is an exact sequence $\mathbb Z/2\to Spin(n)\to SO_n$ with which we recover the 2nd Stiefel--Whitney map $w_2:Prin_{SO_n}(X)\to H^2(X;\mathbb Z/2)$, and $w_2(P)=0$ iff $P\in Prin_{Spin(n)}(X)$, i.e. $P$ is spinnable. The previous term in the induced (cohomology) exact sequence is $H^1(X;\mathbb Z/2)$, corresponding to the set of spin structures up to equivalence.

Comment: The generator $\eta$ is $S^1$ with a spinor bundle that is trivial as a _flat_ vector bundle. The reason is that to realise spin cobordism, it is easiest to consider manifolds with totally geodesic boundary (having a collar would be even better). The circle is bounded by the upper hemisphere in $S^2$, and the natural spinor connection induces a flat connection on the spinor bundle of $S^1$ with holonomy $-1$. Hence the generator of spin bordism must be $S^1$ with the other, i.e., with the trivial spin structure.